# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript

Почему выбивает ошибку для:

```
function toArray(e) {
  return Array.from(e) || Array.prototype.slice.call(e)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не можете вызывать функцию, если не уверены, что она существует (т.е. что `Array.from` определено как функция, а не является `undefined`). Можно так:

```js
function toArray(e) {
  return Array.from ? Array.from(e) : Array.prototype.slice.call(e);
}
```